# How to create/write in xml file using xmlSerializer and store in internal storage android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I am working on an android application and want to create and store some data into an xml file using xmlSerializer, and that file should be save in android internal storage,....here is the i dont know what wrong with it, when i run the app it would give me an error that "Unfortunately project has stopped".. kindly help me on this!

```
package com.example.xmlnizam;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String Filename = "xmlfile.xml"; 
        FileOutputStream fos = null; 
        try 
        {
            fos = openFileOutput(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
            //File path = getFileStreamPath(Filename);  
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File has been created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Creating FIle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

        //XmlSerializer to write into Xml file 
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();  
        try
        {
            xmlSerializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
            xmlSerializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "AllData");
                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Person");
                xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "id", "1");
                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Name");
                    xmlSerializer.text("nomi");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Name");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Age");
                    xmlSerializer.text("21");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Name");

                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Sex");
                    xmlSerializer.text("male");
                    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Name");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "Person");
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "AllData");
            xmlSerializer.endDocument();
            xmlSerializer.flush(); 
            fos.close(); 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Inserting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 


    }
}
```

Comment: please share the logcat logs...

Comment: What is the problem in the above code ???? What is the error ???

Comment: thanx for asking! but i have found the solution already

Comment: Please share your solution, might help others :)

Comment: you should share the code which solved your problem it might help others